# If $u_i$ are affinely independent, are they also linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I am wondering about affinely independent and just linearly independent. [On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) it is explained that $u_i$ are affinely independent if $u_1 - u_0, ...,u_k -u_0$ are linearly independent. It is clear that if $u_i$ are linearly independent then $u_1 - u_0, ...,u_k -u_0$ are linearly independent. Is the other implication not also true? Then what is the difference between the two definitions?

Comment: What if $u_0$ itself is a linear combination of $u_i$'s? Then certainly, $\{u_i-u_0\}$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: **affinely** is for points whereas **linearly** is for vectors.

Comment: @xavierm02 Is the point/vector distinction that important? Also, how do you think about vectors? Do you think of them as just (equivalence class of) arrows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reverse implication is not true, consider the following three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $u_0=e_1, u_1=2e_1$ and $u_2=e_1+e_2$. The three vectors are affinely independent but not linearly independent.

The best way to understand the difference is from the picture on the wikipedia page. Think of $u_0$ as the "base vertex"and all the other $u_i$ as the positions of the other vertices. $u_i-u_0$ is then the position vector of all the other vertices relative to the base vertex, and we need these to be linearly independent (so that $u_0,\dots, u_k$ are affinely independent) so that we don't end up with three collinear vertices which would mess up our idea of what a simplex should be.

It should also be noted that the point $u_0$ is not special in the definition of affine indepenence, but in fact if $u_0,\dots,u_k$ are affinely independent then for anyfor any $j$, $u_0-u_j,\dots,u_k-u_j$ are all linearly independent. Check out this wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_combinations_and_affine_dependence

Comment: The thing is, those two *are* equivalent, so long as $u_i$ are in a vector space. In an abstract affine space, $u_i-u_0$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @tomasz I'm a little confused, which two are equivalent?

Comment: Linear independence of $u_1-u_0,\ldots,u_n-u_0$ and affine independence of $u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_n$.

Comment: @tomasz I see, good point, I'll clarify the answer, thanks!
(In fact, I just deleted the edit, I misinterpreted the "which means" part of the wiki article and as such the edit was unnecessary.)

Comment: @TomOldfield If we only have 2 vectors, then are these two vectors affine independent by definition?