# Conditions under which affine independence equivalent to linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, surfaces, polyhedra

Our professor mentioned in class that for $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \neq 0$ and $x_1, ..., x_k \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ :\ a^Tx = b\}$, $x_1, ..., x_k$ are affinely independent iff they are linearly independent. I don't have good intuition for what affine independence even represents. Would anyone be able to provide insight into why this is true?

Comment: Yes, I understand that equivalence. I believe this statement holds since $x_1, ..., x_k \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\ :\ a^Tx = b\}$.

Comment: Oh ok, yes we will assume $b \neq 0$, I will add that to the claim. Do you have a proof that this claim is false? Or a counterexample?

Comment: @daw: There's no need for the set to contain the zero vector, and in fact we need $b\ne0$, not $b=0$.

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453381/269050 ?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct.

If the $x_i$ are affinely dependent, they are also linearly dependent (since the zero sum exhibiting the affine dependence also exhibits a linear dependence).

Conversely, let $\sum_i\lambda_ix_i=0$. Then $a^\top\sum_i\lambda_ix_i=\sum_i\lambda_ia^\top x_i=\sum_i\lambda_ib=b\sum_i\lambda_i$. Since $b\ne0$, it follows that $\sum_i\lambda_i=0$. Thus the linear dependence is also an affine dependence.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense!